# Is it possible to write a script to change the Energy Saver settings in OS X (10.7.3)?

Tags: macos, script, system-settings

Basically, whenever I know I'm going to be gone, or if I'm going to sleep, I change the Energy Saver settings in System Preferences in OS X (10.7.3) for Power Adapter to:

- Computer sleep: 1 min
- Display sleep: 1 min

If I know I'm going to be around a while, I like to change the Energy Saver settings for Power Adapter to:

- Computer Sleep: 15 min
- Display Sleep: 15 min

Is it possible to script this sort of change? I do it often enough that a script would be worth it.

Comment: Couldn't you just put the computer (⌥⌘⏏) or display (⌃⇧⏏) to sleep manually?

Comment: @Lri: That also works for me. If you put that down as an answer, I'd upvote it. Is there any way to put both to sleep simultaneously?

Comment: Normal sleep should put displays to sleep as well. (If it doesn't on your Mac, you could probably make another question about it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the section titled "Changing Power Management Settings" in this [MacScripter guide](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24773). An AppleScript example from the guide:

> ```
> do shell script "pmset sleep 30" with administrator privileges
> ```

Comment: You can also change the display sleep and store the login password in the script: `do shell script "pmset displaysleep 30" password "somepassword" with administrator privileges`